# Is it possible to force an XMLHttpRequest not to send cookies in chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to force chrome not to send the cookie header on an XMLHttpRequest. I see that Firefox has an anon parameter, but is there something similar on chrome/webkit?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way in webextensions at the moment (both in Firefox and Chrome). Let us look at the alternatives:

1. Use [`fetch`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) instead of XMLHttpRequest
2. Modify request headers using the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Option 1 has the charm that it does not involve hacks, but the downside is that `fetch` is currently still missing some functionality that exists in `XMLHttpRequest`. Whether that is a problem, depends on your concrete example.

Option 2 requires permission to use the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), which requires additional permissions. Also it looks more complicated than it should be. Still, it is the only way that I got working and which can be used on today's browsers (Nov 2017).

But let us look at both options in detail.

**Option 1: fetch API and its limitations**

When you mention anonymous requests in Firefox, I'm sure you mean code like this:

```
let xhr = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com');
xhr.channel.loadFlags |= Components.interfaces.nsIRequest.LOAD_ANONYMOUS;
xhr.send();
```

With `XMLHttpRequest` in Chrome it is not possible, but the closest thing that you can get today is to avoid sending cookies by using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which has a similar option called [`credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials), which lets you control whether cookies should be included (`'include'`) or not (`'omit'`):

```
fetch('http://www.example.com', { credentials: 'omit' }).then(...);
```

This will make a GET request without setting any cookies.

There are still some limitations in terms of functionality in comparison to `XMLHttpRequest`. The most pressing issue from my perspective is that you cannot abort requests started with `fetch`, nor do you have control over timeouts.

There is a new standard to support abortable `fetch` (see [AbortController API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)), but it is currently only implemented on Firefox 57 and Edge (in Nov 2017). It will soon arrive in Chrome, but if you need the functionality now, it might not be an option to wait until all browsers support it.

Still, once `AbortController` is there, I assume it will become the preferred way to avoid sending cookies.

**Option 2: webRequest API and removing the 'Cookie' header manually**

If you need a working solution now, and you have permission in the extension to access the webRequest API, you can install a [`onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) listener and manually remove the `Cookie` header.

To get an idea, this is how it could look like:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener((details) => {
  return {
    requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase() !== 'cookie');
  };
}, { urls: ['<all_urls>'] }, ['requestHeaders', 'blocking']);
```

But you have to be careful that you do not accidentally modify unrelated requests. In a real implementation, you should verify whether the `details.requestId` matches. To get access to the request id, I used another [onBeforeRequestListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) and verified whether the URL of the request seems to match. When the request is done, all listeners are removed again. (For more details, see [How to get the requestId of a new request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47331875/783510).)

From what I see, it works but it is not a very elegant solution.

**Summary:**

fetch API:

- (+) Straightforward solution via `crendentials: 'omit'`
- (+) New standard which is intended to replace `XMLHttpRequest`
- (-) Current browsers do not yet support all features (timeouts, cancellation)

webRequest API:

- (+) works on today's browsers (tested on Chrome)
- (-) very complex solution for a simple problem
- (-) requires extra permissions to use it