# webextension: Why does the browser add a trailing slash to the requested URL?

Tags: javascript, http, url, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I make a request to `http://www.example.com`, why does I see `http://www.example.com/` in the [webRequest.onBeforeRequestListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest)?

For example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  details => console.log('Sending request to', details.url),
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] });
fetch('http://www.example.com');
```

will print

```
Sending request to http://www.example.com/
```

That is consistent with the request URL shown in the network request monitor. For example, if I take it and convert it to a curl command, the request looks like this:

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9'
    -H 'User-Agent: ...' --compressed
```

So, the original request that goes out is for `http://www.example.com/` not for `http://www.example.com`. That decision must have been made in the browser, not by the server.

The same behavior also occurs when using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch`. In my example, I used Chrome, but on Firefox it is the same.

**Questions:**

- Why does the browser change it automatically? It also happens with other URLs. From my understanding, adding a trailing slash will often work, but in general, it is a breaking change.
- If I want to filter in the `onBeforeRequest` listener for the current request to a specific URL, how can you reliably match it? For instance, just checking whether the URLs are identical will fail.
- Are there more rewrite URL rules in the browser to be aware of?

Comment: Some other answers regarding the trailing slash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581411/do-web-browsers-always-send-a-trailing-slash-after-a-domain-name, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Comment: @PredatorIWD Thanks for the link. That seems to confirm what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think, I found it. The browser is just fixing an invalid URL.

To cite from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), a URL looks like this:

`scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`

> The path must begin with a single slash (/) if an authority part was present, and may also if one was not, but must not begin with a double slash. The path is always defined, though the defined path may be empty (zero length), therefore no trailing slash.

`http://example.com` has an authority part (in this example, the schema plus hostname: `http://example.com`), but that leaves the path empty. According to the specification, the path must start with a `/`, so the browser fixes it by replacing the empty path by `/`.

If you use a valid URL instead, like `http://example.com/abc`, it does not need to modify it.

Comment: AFAIR this comes from HTTP RFCs. And here is the relevant quote https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581514/529442

Comment: @Philip, I don't think this is fixing URL, Kindly look at this question posted by me, here "/" is not getting added by itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233565/need-to-route-to-specific-page-if-i-enter-url-with-path

Comment: @SupRaviKumar There is a difference between a technical invalid URL like `http://example.com` and a valid URL like `http://example.com/abc`. Only in the first case, the "/" will be added (as described in my answer). In your linked question, it covers the second case. The browser will not change it since the URL is well-formed and changing it could change its meaning.