# Need to route to specific page If I enter URL with path

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

There are two ASP.NET Web Form App under one domain by using virtual directory EMR and EMRSSO in IIS server:

https://test.xyz.com/emr
https://test.xyz.com/emrsso

When I enter URL in browser for https://test.xyz.com/emr, It automatically append "/" in URL and provide expected response.
This app is not using URL Routing and using Form Authentication for login.

And when I enter URL in browser for https://test.xyz.com/emrsso, It don't append "/" in URL and does not provide expected response.
This app is using URL Routing:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Home", String.Empty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomePage"))
```

and using Token ID drom third party app for login.

I want that

1. If I enter URL https://test.xyz.com/emrsso then it should redirect to specific aspx page which i configured in app setting or atleast append "/" in URL.
2. Why is both behaving differnety in same browser if I am entering same pattern url.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below to routes and then It worked fine:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "EMRSSO", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomePage"))
```